# Retrieving a contact picture for a MAPI address book entry

Tags: c++, mapi

I needed access to the private address books of a user in Windows.

The software I am working on is using C++ and using anything else is not an option.

I solved all the problems except for how to access the photos that are stored with the contacts in Outlook (or any other MAPI address book provider).

The information I need:

- What format are those pictures stored in?
- Which property type (PR_XXX) is my code supposed to query for?

But maybe those pictures cannot be retrieved like other properties of the contact (e.g. like surname or email address)

Comment: You extracting the pictures from GAL or OAB contacts?

Comment: In this particular case from OAB only. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

In case of OAB, you will need to extract the IPM.Conntact message entry id property from the address book entry id (OAB entry id format is documented on MSDN), open the message, then read its attachments. The picture attachment will have PR_ATTACHMENT_CONTACTPHOTO property set to true